# What caused the machine to fly after the piece seprated?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

In [this](https://youtu.be/6XYen9SO2yo?t=32) video, after the piece with the camera separates from the main rotating machine, what causes it(the main rotating machine) to come off the attachments and fly off into the air? Is it due to less weight at one end due to the small piece with the camera flying off or is it due to some other reason?
Can anybody please explain this to me as I am having trouble understanding it

https://youtu.be/6XYen9SO2yo?t=32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think if the rotating part had been precisely balanced, it would not have been torn from its axis. Probably it was not balanced, so the axis attachment failed, the rotating part had some momentum (because of the lack of balance) and started to move by inertia.

Comment: do you mean "I would think if the rotating part had been precisely balanced, it would not have been torn from the  (Attaching it to floor)

Comment: @AviationEnthusiast : or from the geometric axis

Comment: Since this is the only answer, I'm marking it as accepted